# How to view the filter graph used by Windows Media Player

Tags: windows-media-player, mp4, avisynth, directshow

i have a video that i cannot render in Graph Edit:

[image]

GSpot cannot render:

[image]

and AVISynth's DirectShowSource cannot open:

[image]

And yet Windows Media Player (12) can play it fine.

How can i figure out the filters that Windows Media Player is using, when DirectShow itself cannot render the file?

---

i tried running GraphEdit as an adminstrator and connecting to a remote graph, but Windows Media Player does not register its graph in the running objects table:

[image]

Related question: How can i access a file in AviSynth that Windows Media Player can play, but DirectShow cannot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the tag, I assume that this is a .mp4 video file?

Instead of DirectShow, WMP 12 can use the newer Media Foundation framework for rendering files. This is the case for MPEG-4 files.

For the Media Foundation equivalent of GraphEdit, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333728/is-there-something-like-graphedit-for-mediafoundation).

Comment: Untested, but that sounds very likely.